# bash function does not show me date or cat arguments completely

Tags: bash, shell-script, output

I am writing a bash script for backup with log storage.

- I use my defined function as follows:

  ```bash
  logit () {
      echo " $1  $2 "  >> /path/to/log
  }
  ```
- For `logit 'Starting Backup' $(date +'%D %T')` I get this output:

  ```
  Starting Backup 01/11/22
  ```

  so the time is missing, apparently the `stdout` function has shortened it.
- With `echo $(date +'%D %T')` I also get the time in the `stdout`.
- I would also like to use my function for logs, e.g.

  ```bash
  logit 'DB-LOGS' $(cat /path/to/sql)
  ```

  results in

  ```
  DB-LOG mysqldump:
  ```

  Again, some stdout is missing here.

What should I change or add to the function to get complete output?

Comment: Related - [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/100397)

Comment: Also: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)

Comment: With bash (or ksh93 where bash copied that (a small subset of) from), you could do `printf '%s %(%D %T)T\n' 'Starting backup' -1`. In `zsh`, you can do time stamping with prompt expansion or the `strftime` builtin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double quote the command substitution:

```
logit 'Starting Backup' "$(date +'%D %T')"
```

Without quotes, the result of `$(date ...)` goes through word splitting and filename globbing. There's no shortening: assuming `$IFS` is still set to its default value (which does contain the space character), the date and time are passed as separate arguments to the function, the time ends up in `$3` which you don't use.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `"$*"` in your script to concatenate all parameters to one string.

```
logit () {
    echo " $* "  >> /path/to/log
}
```

(`"$*"` uses the first character of `IFS` as joiner, a space by default.)

Or, if you want the extra spaces around each arg, use `printf` with `"$@"`:

```
logit () {
    { printf " %s " "$@"; echo; } >> /path/to/log
}
```

(Here, `"$@"` expands to each arg separately, and `printf` repeats the format string as many times as needed. `echo` adds the final newline.)

Comment: If you want to create a single string from the positional parameters, use `$*` inside the quoted string. If you want to create multiple arguments for `echo`, use `"$@"` with no spaces around `$@`.

Comment: @they The " $@ " is also a single argument. I thought it closer to the OP's intention.

Comment: `" $@ "` is two arguments if there are two positional parameters (the same as `" $1" "$2 "`).  You would recreate `" $1 $2 "` with `" $* "`, assuming the first character of `$IFS` is a space.

Comment: Strange, ksh tells me differently, concerning the " $@ ".

Comment: Which `ksh` is that? Both `pdksh` and `ksh93` produces two lines from `set -- "a b" "c d"; printf '"%s"\n' " $@ "`.  This user tagged their question with [tag:bash], and that shell behaves the same, as does `dash`.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, `"$@"` results in multiple arguments, `"$*"` produces one. Here, with two args, it's the difference between `echo "$1" "$2"` and `echo "$1 $2"`. ...which in the case of `echo` is hard to tell, since `echo` itself does the same as `"$*"` (with default `IFS`), it joins the args with spaces in between. But `"$*"` is arguably more "correct" here, and as said, you'd see the difference with e.g. `printf "%s\n" "$@"`.